# Importing Existing Android Project into Eclipse: SRC and Loading XML Errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting an error where in my SRC folder, all the files have an error and in my loading xml, there's an error too. Is there a way to fix this or a proper way to import an existing android project into Eclipse?

Here is the process that I went to import my project:

```
File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next
Select root directory: /path/to/project
Projects → Select All
Uncheck Copy projects into workspace and Add project to working sets
Finish
```

Comment: Did you try to clean project and close and open eclipse? I got similar error as i deleted my appcompat v7 folder in eclipse. Look if your project have access to appcompat just a hint can't provide more infis because im one the phone hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, I clean the project and restarted eclipse. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To import an existing android project files into eclipse, on the file tab  click import click import and browse to choose or select. WHen this is done packaged